# add JSON body to axios instance

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, get, axios

I've got an axios Instance configured like this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${config.API_BASE_URL}`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

instance.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    console.log('Starting Request', JSON.stringify(request, null, 2))
    return request
})

instance.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    console.log('Response:', JSON.stringify(response, null, 2))
    return response
})
```

Now I'm trying to create a GET request which adds a JSON as body to my Instance:

```
function findByFilter(textTokens, tags) {
    var body = JSON.stringify({textTokens: textTokens, searchFavHashtagsList: tags})
    var res = instance.get('/api/search/filter', {
        data: body
    })
    return res
}
```

I've tested the API with postman, there everything is working fine. I think I'm passing the JSON / body the wrong way?!

How do I declare my body for such a request?

Comment: I think you can't really use a body with a GET request. Maybe axios is ignoring your body? Have you checked the axios docs? Consider adding the parameters to your request as URL params

Answer (score 0):

You can't attach a body to a get request. You can pass data through params in a similar way

```
    const response = await axiosInstance.get('/', {
          params: { id: 1234, name: 'john' },
        });
```

https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/get-with-data